# PlaceHolder In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005, placeholder

Actually I am new here and not familiar about placeholder. Just hear about it and find generally in ASP.Net.

my question is PlaceHolder is not available in local C# is there any similar control is there or not then how to access the PlaceHolder in local C# Application.

Guide me Please.

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder is an Asp.net control which you drag from the toolbox on your page.
There is no such thing in C#

Here is an example of how to use it:

http://www.aspxcode.net/free-asp-net-sample-source-code-c.aspx?Topics=How%20to%20Use%20PlaceHolder

Hope that helps.

Comment: so in C# any other similar control is available?

Comment: Actually the controls are not in C#. They are in your .net framework. Also third parties develop custom (commercial) controls for winforms or webforms (asp.net) which you can add to your visual studio toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

With 'local' You mean so called win forms? Maybe wpf?

In win forms it would be 'Panel' control if I remember correctly.

Comment: can u tell me how i can drow two textbox in panel like below.

textbox1                                            textbox2

 the two textbox in same row but left of textbox change in dynamically and scroll it the same

Comment: Typically You drag it from visual studio toolbox. 'Changing something dynamically' involves handling so called control events (OnClick, OnChanged, etc.) and that inevitably leads to understanding what is happening and writing some code. I think You should spend more time reading some tutorials on this subject.

Comment: Wow... winforms are quite out-dated. Quite hard to find decent tutorials. Anyway this one might teach You something - http://bit.ly/9nVqFa